# How to set up the boundary condition for piecewise pde?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In the $R^3$ space, there is a ball with radius $r$. Inside the ball, there is a uniform heat source $f(t)$. Then the heat equation inside the ball is $u_t + k_1\nabla^2 u = f(t)$. And $u_t + k_2\nabla^2 u = 0$ outside the ball. The solution has to be continuous, then $u^{+}(r,t) = u^{-}(r,t)$. But how do I makes them to be twice differentiable? And for the $u$ in the ball, I can get a general solution using fundamental solution. The initial condition is just $u(x,0) = u_0$ which is a constant. How do I solve for the outside? And what boundary condition should I assume for the outside?

Comment: @Gonçalo So do I assume any boundary condition for the pde inside the ball?

Comment: @Gonçalo Yes that is what I am seeking. I used to use the point heat source that is resulting infinite solution at the center. So I make the heat source to be a ball. But the problem is I cannot assume there is a heat sink at the surface. And the temperature at the surface definitely affect the solution in the ball.